# Captcha does not work in chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, captcha

I use *[Simple PHP Captcha](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/01/a-simple-php-captcha-script/)* in a form and it works fine in Firefox, Opera and IE but not in Chrome. The image loads fine and I am able to pass the captcha code but it fails when I try to check it like this:

```
if( $_POST['CaptchaCode'] === $_SESSION['captcha']['code'] )
```

when I `echo $_POST['CaptchaCode']` I get the correct code that I have entered but when I `echo $_SESSION['captcha']['code']` then I get different code than I saw in captcha. It looks like it was newly generated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it is related to your browser ? That seems really odd because everything here is server-sided.
If you go there (http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/simple-php-captcha/) with Chrome, is there a difference between the image and the code in the var_dump ?

Comment: I am sure it works on my PC in Firefox, Opera and IE but not in Chrome. When I go to the site you have written it works as it should even in Chrome. But there is a difference. The page you have posted uses probably only one php file unlike my page which sends the form data to another php file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The "Simple PHP Captcha" wasn't working only in Chrome.

My case is probably very specific, but can be helpful. Firstly, you need to know, that:

- My app returns a 404 error page, which contains contact form with CAPTCHA.
- Google Chrome looks for a `favicon.ico` even if you don't declare any favicon in your `<head>` section. In that case Chrome looks in the root (`/favicon.ico`).

The rest is pretty obvious :) At my server there was no favicon, so my "contact us" page loaded with a CAPTCHA image, but additionaly google sent a request for favicon.ico, my server returned 404 error page, which also contains contact form with CAPTCHA which rewrited code in `$_SESSION`.

So I solved this issue simply by adding a favicon.ico :)

To make this answer more general, the problem is for sure, that the CAPTCHA code gets regenerated from some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution which is not perfect but it works. I have added a hidden input in my form which containt hashed correct code like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hashCode" value=<?php echo "'" . md5($_SESSION['captcha']['code']) . "'" ?>>
```

and then I perform the check:

```
if( md5(strtoupper($_POST['captchaCode'])) === $_POST['hashCode'] )
```

Now it works also in Chrome. But I would still like to know why after a form is submited in Chrome the `$_SESSION['captcha']['code']` changes.

Comment: Are you submitting the form to a page where $_SESSION['captcha'] = captcha(); is present (like submitting it to the same page) ? Because if you do, a new captcha code is genrated, and it would be pretty normal that it changes.

Comment: Then I don't see any reason why it doesn't work. One note for you : Your workaround goes directly at the opposite purpose of the captcha (Know if it is really a human that fills the captcha). MD5 isn't secure anymore, and huge hash dictionnaries already exist. So you definitely shouldn't post it in your page, as a good programmer won't have any difficulty to find what was the captcha code from the MD5.

Comment: Thanks for your interest and note. I know that it should not be done this way but I didn't know that MD5 is easy to break.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue, in my case it was the adBlocker extension installed in Chrome was blocking the rendering of the Captcha.
I was using Ghostery.

Try to disable all the ad-blockers you have installed.